# How can I fix this error that I get from setting a character of a string equal to a element of a vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a program that converts decimal numbers to a certain base and then finding how many times the largest number (1-8) in that base appears.

```cpp
string conv(int decimal, int base);
vector<int>base10nums;
vector<string>differentbase;

int main(){
    int num,base,start;
    cin>>num>>base>>start;
    for(int i=0;i<num;++i){
        base10nums.push_back(start+i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num;++i){
        string x=conv(base10nums[i],base);
        differentbase.push_back(x);
    }
    int u=0;
    int largestdigit=base-1;
    for(int i=0;i<num;++i){
        string l=differentbase[i];    //error here
        for(int j=0;j<differentbase[i].length();++i){
            if(largestdigit==8){
                if(l[j]=='8'){          //error here
                     u++;
                }
            }
            if(largestdigit==7){
               if(l[j]=='7'){
                     u++;
               } 
            }
            if(largestdigit==6){
                if(l[j]=='6'){
                     u++;
               }
            }
            if(largestdigit==5){
                if(l[j]=='5'){
                     u++;
               }
            }
            if(largestdigit==4){
                if(l[j]=='4'){
                     u++;
               }
            }
            if(largestdigit==3){
                if(l[j]=='3'){
                     u++;
               }
            }
            if(largestdigit==2){
                if(l[j]=='2'){
                     u++;
               }
            }
            if(largestdigit==1){
                if(l[j]=='1'){
                     u++;
               }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<<u;
}

std::string conv(int decimal, int base){
    if(decimal == 0) return "0";
    char NUMS[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    std::string result = "";
    do{
        result.push_back(NUMS[decimal%base]);
        decimal /= base; 
    }while(decimal != 0); 
    return std::string(result.rbegin(), result.rend());
}
```

In the part with a bunch of `if`s, I'm trying to compare each digit in each number in base `base` to the largest digit. I can run the program, but I don't get the right value and when I hover over the `l[j]` part in VSCode, I get the error:

> "inline char &std::string::operator[](std::size_t __pos)
> +1 overload
>
> Subscript access to the data contained in the %string.
>
> Parameters:
> __pos – The index of the character to access.
>
> Returns:
> Read/write reference to the character. This operator allows for easy, array-style, data access. Note that data access with this operator is unchecked and out_of_range lookups are not defined. (For checked lookups see `at()`.)"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have described a quick info tooltip in VS Code, not an error message.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It [runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/), this is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?